# How to work with promises using AngularJs factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have angularJs getter and setter factory to get `processkey` , setter is working as expected and i do have `processKey` in `processFactory` but when i call `getProcessid` from controller it throws below error.

How can i resolve this issue using AngularJS ?

ctrl.js

```
   processFactory.setProcessId($stateParams.processId);


    processFactory.getProcessId().then(function(response){
                  var processKey = response;
                  consoel.log('PROCESSKEY GETTER',processKey)
                });
```

factory.js

```
 setProcessId: function(id){
          processKey = id;
        },
 getProcessId: function(){
          return processKey;
        }
```

ERROR

```
angular.js:11594 TypeError: processFactory.getProcessId(...).then is not a function
```

Comment: getProcessId is returning an ID; it needs to return a promise and then resolve that promise.   (I am assuming that in real life this would be async code, otherwise promises are unnecessary here)

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no asyn operation, so you could have done simply -

```
$cookies.put("", token);
var processKey = processFactory.getProcessId();
```

If you want to do some asynchronous operation inside the function, then you might want to use promise... still if you want to make your controller code work, you may write something like this :-

```
       getProcessId: function(){
                var defer = $q.defer();               
                defer.resolve(processKey);
                return defer.promise;
        }
```

Comment: How can i destroy the value once its set because it only needed for some scenarios but its keep coming in controller all the time

Comment: You can have another function in you factory that can do that, or you can simple reset the value using your set function.